# Admob banner view displays incorrectly in a NavigationViewController

Tags: ios, admob

I am facing a  strange problem with admob for iOS. It displays correctly in a ViewController, but while embedding it to a NavigationViewController, the admob contents seem to have some top padding. Please see the screenshots:

- In a ViewController without NavigationViewController
  [image: Admob Banner View in a ViewController]
- In a ViewController embedded in NavigationViewController
  [image: Admob Banner View in a ViewController embedded in NavigationViewController]
- Xcode: 6.2 (6C131e)
- Admob SDK: 7.2.1
- Sample: [MyAdmob](http://file.js-cambodia.com/tmp/MyAdmob.zip)

Comment: how do you give position of bannerview

Comment: Please check the position using enable or write logs. Seems some positioning issue.

Comment: I've use auto-layout. The position looks ok. I also set the border to the banner view. Please see the updated screenshots.